# What does each element of the Klein 4-group represent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'm new to the concept of the Klein 4-group. I am familiar with the concept of the alternating group and what elements like (1 2 3) represent. However the Klein 4-group contains elements like (1 2)(3 4) which is not clear to me. What does (1 2)(3 4) represent?

Comment: An even permutation that is also an involution? Also, the klein group within $\;S_4\;$ ia normal subgroup, the minimal such one that is transitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the decomposition of a permutation as a product of disjoint cycles Thus this permutation swaps $1$ and $2$ on one hand, $3$ and $4$  on the other hand. Another notation would be
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&1&4&3\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Just to be clear, do alternating groups also contain such elements?

Comment: All permutations can be written as a product of disjoint cycles. This one is an element of $A_4$. Actually *Klein's Vierergruppe* is a normal subgroup of $A_4$.